# Apache POI Java Read using Member Class Variable

Tags: java, excel, maven, apache-poi

Hi how can i create dynamic objects in a loop to store multiple values in the object. Then access those objects to manipulate.

Is it possible to give dynamic variable names for object creation. Can i give dynamic values of variable on the left hand side of an assignment. Please ask me to edit if the question is not clear, if solution already available please point me out to that.

```
package poi;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class ExcelRead_UsingMember {
    public static int C, R, i;
    public static double ID;
    private static final String FILE_READ = "C:/Users/m93162/ApachePOI_Excel_Workspace/MyFirstExcel.xlsx";
    //private static final String FILE_WRITE = "C:/Users/m93162/ApachePOI_Excel_Workspace/WriteExcel.xlsx";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Member> listOfMembers = new ArrayList<Member>();

        try {
            FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(FILE_READ));
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
            Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();

             while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                    Row currentRow = iterator.next();
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();

                    int i=0;

                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                        Member [member+i] = new Member();
QUESTION: I want to create dynamic objects here and store the values below dynamically. How to approach this.

                        Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();


                        if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                            System.out.print(currentCell.getStringCellValue() + "--");
                        } else if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                            System.out.print(currentCell.getNumericCellValue() + "--");
                        }

                    }
                    System.out.println();

                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: My requirement needs a Member class to define multiple datatypes...can anyone try this please

Answer (score 2):

You can use map.

`DynamicObject`

```
DynamicObject {
     prvate Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap();

     public void addPropery(String key, Object value) {
          map.put(key, value);
     }
}
```

`Your code`

```
private void processRow(Row row) {
    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
        dynamicObjects[member+i] = new DynamicObject();
        DynamicObject dynamicObject = dynamicObjects[member+i];
        Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();

        if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
            System.out.print(currentCell.getStringCellValue() + "--");
                        dynamicObject.addProperty("stringField", currentCell.getStringCellValue());
        } else if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
             System.out.print(currentCell.getNumericCellValue() + "--");
                        dynamicObject.addProperty("numericField", currentCell.getNumericCellValue());
        }

    }
}
```

Then you can traverse keys of the map to get all possible values. You can also store other objects(for example, as nested maps) inside the map as values.

Comment: can u explain what is //dynamicObjects[member+i]
I gave [member+i] to define a concatenation, like showing an example in my code